# how to use a wp plugin as a theme part not as a plugin?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, themes

I am developing a word press theme and I have a free plugin which helps me to add new features to my theme. I want to use this plugin in this theme but I don't want to use it as a plugin and have to activate in plugins section. I want to use it as a theme part and disable activating or deactivating it. It will be activate automatically when theme set up.

Comment: Just add the plugin within your theme's functions.php file.

Answer (score 0):

If your theme uploaded somewhere then refer -> https://wordimpress.com/how-to-easily-require-plugins-for-your-wordpress-themes/ 
Or

```
add_action( 'admin_notices', 'my_theme_dependencies' );

function my_theme_dependencies() {
  if( ! function_exists('plugin_function') )
    echo '<div class="error"><p>' . __( 'Warning: The theme needs Plugin X to function', 'my-theme' ) . '</p></div>';
}
```

OR
if your theme is in local setup then you can use must-up plugin, for that refer -> https://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins

Comment: I looked them sorry but I don't understand how I can do it. Maybe I couldn't explain what I wanted. Now I have a plugin and a website. I am developing this website with localhost. I want to combine this plugin with this website. I dont want to see neither the plugin name or plugin settings in dashboard of wordpress. This is a post like and dislike plugin. It doesn't require to style. My question is: where should I store this plugin folder in the theme folder and how can i activate it with writing code in function.php?

Comment: place your plugin file inside "wp-content/mu-plugins". ( place only php file, don't add the folder inside it. ) Using this way your added plugin will be auto-activated with any active WordPress theme. Now your plugin will not be deactivated or delete anyway.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand correctly you want your plugin to be in Wordpress but you don't want it to be shown to anyone else or be able to deactivate it?

Try using this plugin, which will hide your plugin('s) from everyone - [WP Hide Plugins](https://wordpress.org/plugins/hide-plugins/).

**Or** add this to your functions.php file:

```
function hide_plugin_trickspanda() {
  global $wp_list_table;
  $hidearr = array('plugin-directory/plugin-file.php');
  $myplugins = $wp_list_table->items;
  foreach ($myplugins as $key => $val) {
    if (in_array($key,$hidearr)) {
      unset($wp_list_table->items[$key]);
    }
  }
}

add_action('pre_current_active_plugins', 'hide_plugin_trickspanda');
```

**Info to go with this code:** rename the plugin name in the first line, also change the "plugin-directory/plugin-file.php" to the plugin file of your plugin and in the last line change the plugin name too.